# How to get staged diffs for commit?

Tags: gitpython

I want to obtain a list of differences that are staged for commit (basically the equivalent of "git diff --cached").

I'm using gitpython. I have found that I can get a list of staged files easily enough, but as soon as I request generation of a diff, the list becomes empty.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from git import Repo

myrepo = Repo()  # current directory

staged_files = myrepo.index.diff(myrepo.head.commit, create_patch=False)
print(staged_files)

staged_blobs = myrepo.index.diff(myrepo.head.commit, create_patch=True)
print(staged_blobs)
```

What I get is this:

```sh
[<git.diff.Diff object at 0x7f52753c7710>, <git.diff.Diff object at 0x7f527538f200>]
[]
```

Namely, the first call gives me a list of Diff objects, with each entry corresponding to one of my staged files, but the second call gives me an empty list.

Why does the second call not give me the same list as the first, but with difference information incorporated?

Is there some other approach I'm supposed to use to obtain this information?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug -- I found a writeup, and the workaround, in [GitPython issue 852](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/852).

The workaround is to add argument `R=True` to the argument list when `create_patch=True` and the first argument is not None; the details are in the analysis.